# error al utilizar select exists mysql phpmyadmin

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

trato de hacer una consulta a la base de datos verificando si un correo electronico que se desea registrar ya se encuentra utilizado por otro registro o no, devolviendo un true o false, tengo la siguiente consulta:

```
SELECT EXISTS(SELECT column_correoelectronico FROM persona WHERE column_correoelectronico = 'correoelectronico@outlook.com');
```

pero phpmyadmin no me deja ejecutar la consulta porque hay un error, y no se cual puede ser el error si esa consulta la saque de [aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1676573/9579502) y les funciona bien.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La consulta en realidad no tiene problemas, pero para que la consulta te devuelva 0 o 1 indicándote que el correo existe o no en la tabla en cuestión tendrías que realizar el `select` al valor `1` quedando de esta forma

```
SELECT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM persona WHERE column_correoelectronico = 'correoelectronico@outlook.com');
```

Espero te haya podido ayudar

Comment: me sigue saliendo error cuando lo introduzco en el phpmyadmin, sale errores como `se esperaba una expresion cerca EXISTS`, `palabra clave no reconocida cerca de EXISTS`, por otra parte intente hacer esta consulta preparada `$stmt = $conexion->prepare("SELECT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM persona WHERE column_correoelectronico = 'ninguno')")`, `$resultado = $stmt->execute()`, `echo($resultado)` y la consulta se ejecuta pero me devuelve un 1 diciendome que existe un correo electronico denominado 'ninguno' pero sin embargo no hay ningun correo electronico 'ninguno' en la base de datos.

Comment: Si, hice el mismo ejercicio que tu ejecutandolo primeramente en phpmyadmin, y al igual que tu me daba los mismos errores, pero me ejecutaba la consulta sin problemas donde probe con un correo que existia retornandome 1 y cuando ponia uno que no existia me retornaba cero.

Comment: Ahora bien, tu me dices que `$stmt->execute()` te retorna 1, y eso esta correcto, ya que te esta retornando un `true` indicandote que la consulta se realizo, no te esta mostrando el resultado de la consulta que es muy distinto. Tendrias que realizar lo siguiente `$result = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC); print_r($result);` ahi tendras el resultado de la consulta, que será 0 o 1

Comment: ahh bien bien gracias, funciona, pero que es lo que hace `$stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)`

Comment: Obtiene los resultados de su consulta, mira https://www.php.net/manual/es/pdostatement.fetch.php

Comment: hacer `$stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)` no es lo mismo que hacer `$arg=[PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION, PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE => PDO::FETCH_ASSOC]`, `$conexion = new PDO("mysql:host={$db_host}; dbname={$db_nombre}", $db_usuario, $db_clave, $arg)`?. tengo ese arreglo de argumentos que luego son seteados en la conexion.